# Como criar um evento para um botão no Swing/Java

Tags: javascript, java, swing, javafx, gui

Galera, queria vim pedir um favor, queria que alguém me mostrasse como criar um evento de um JButton, tipo, um botão q quando vc clica nele ele abre outro JFrame e fecha o antigo

usem esse codigo como exemplo

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class inicio{

    public void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton bta = new JButton(“Clique aqui”);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

ai a pessoa clica no botão “clica aqui” e abre outro JFrame e fecha o que estava aberto, obs: expliquem da maneira mais simples possivel e evitem colocar linhas para o programa ficar mais bonito

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método `addActionListener` do seu `JButton` para passar uma interface funcional para o botão. Interface funcional é uma interface que implementa um único método, esse método será invocado quando o botão ser clicado.

Um `JButton` espera uma interface do tipo `ActionListener`, o qual possui o método chamado `actionPerformed`. Você pode implementar essa interface diretamente dentro da chamada do método:

```
bta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Seu código aqui
    }
});
```

Ou ainda, se estiver utilizando a versão 8 ou superior do Java, você pode reduzir a quantidade de "boilerplate" (código repetitivo) usando a sintaxe `lambda`.

```
bta.addActionListener(e -> {
    // Seu código aqui
});
```